# normalization constant for categorical distribution as exponential family

Tags: multinomial-distribution, graphical-model, exponential-family, variational-bayes

Let r.v. $X$ has categorical distribution. We can represent its pmf as $f(x\mid\vec{p})=\Pi_{i=1}^{K}p_i^{I[x=i]}=\exp[\sum_{i=1}^{K}I[x=i]\ln p_i]$, there is no explicit normalization constant [(categorical distribution, variant 1)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family). If we use the fact that $\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i=1$, we can represent $p_K$ as $1-\sum_{i=1}^{K-1}p_i$, and the normalization constant (inside the exponent) can be written as $\ln[1+\sum_{i=1}^{K-1}\exp(\ln\frac{p_i}{p_K})]$ [categorical distribution, variant 3](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_family).

Now we need a normalization constant re-parametrized by the natural parameter vector (for variational message passing). The variant 1 has no such constant, while the variant 3 is too complicated. We note that we can incorporate $\sum p_i=1$ into variant 1 by adding $g(\mathbf{\ln p})=(\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i-1)=(\sum_{i=1}^K\exp(\ln p_i)-1)$ into the exponent. And we have $\frac{\text{d}g(\ln\mathbf{p})}{\text{d}\ln\mathbf{p}}=\langle\exp(\ln p_1),\dots,\exp(\ln p_K)\rangle=\langle p_1,\dots,p_K\rangle$, where each term is positive since $X$ has a categorical distribution.

However, according to [formula (10)](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume6/winn05a/winn05a.pdf), $-\frac{\text{d}g(\ln\mathbf{p})}{\text{d}\ln\mathbf{p}}>0$ for a categorical r.v. $X$, i.e. each term in $\frac{\text{d}g(\ln\mathbf{p})}{\text{d}\ln\mathbf{p}}$ is negative, which contradicts with the above conclusion. And if we change our normalization constant from $(\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i-1)$ to $(1-\sum_{i=1}^Kp_i)=(1-\sum_{i=1}^K\exp(\ln p_i))$, the problem is solved.

Can any one explain it? Is there anything wrong in my calculus?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your question, the formula $g(\ln \textbf{p})$ you derived is missing a minus sign. The term $g$ in Formula (9) of the VMP paper has plus before it.

When we deal with multinomial distribution in Variational Message Passing, we usually use the unnormalized parametrization $p\left( {x|\theta } \right) = \exp \left( {{\theta ^ \top }x - \log \sum\limits_{i = 1}^K {{e^{{\theta _i}}}} } \right)$, where $\theta$ is not normalized. This is conceptually simple. Here $x$ is a one-hot vector. The statistics you gather from the neighbors is simply $E(x)$, which equals to $\frac{{dg\left( \theta  \right)}}{{d\theta }}$ when $g(\theta) = - \log \sum\limits_{i = 1}^K {{e^{{\theta _i}}}}$ above. However solving the equation you can only get a normalized vector $\theta$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Now I think my solution by simply adding the term is incorrect. The parameters have d.o.f. $K-1$. In the two tries above ($\sum p_i-1$ and $1-\sum p_i$), I still used natural parameter vectors at length $K$, which is unlikely to generate correct result. The $\sum p_i-1$ version doesn't generate correct result is understandable, since the calculus is wrong. One thing interesting is that $1-\sum p_i$ indeed led to the correct result. I think it's very likely to be just a coincidence. Is my current understanding correct? Is it due to coincidence or the intrisic corectness?

Comment: By last "it", I mean the fact that adding $1-\sum p_i$ leads to the correct result.